# Who's the most powerful critic of Xi within the CCP?

Tags: china, chinese-communist-party, xi-jinping

> Before Channel NewsAsia released the second video documenting what
> happened before, there were many commentaries on the first video
> recording. James Palmer, a deputy editor at Foreign Policy,
> interpreted the incident to have been political, suggesting that it
> could have been Xi's intention to "deliberately and publicly humiliate
> his predecessor."[72] Xi had been harshly critical in his previous
> speeches, where he spoke of "the problem that the party's leadership
> had been weakened, blurred, diluted, and marginalized" (Chinese:
> "党的领导弱化、虚化、淡化、边缘化问题") before his leadership.[72][73][74] The Economist
> said that while it is possible the act was deliberate, it was more
> likely that Hu was not feeling well, saying that the event "looked
> consistent with a sudden episode of mental confusion".[75] Jude
> Blanchette, an expert at the Center for Strategic and International
> Studies, said that the event "didn't have the stage-managed feel of an
> orchestrated purge",[57] while Bill Bishop, a China expert, noted that
> the China Central Television would likely never show Hu during the
> news footage of the event if he was purged.[76]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hu_Jintao

Many speculated that Hu Jintao who had a very unaggressive foreign policy against the West, was purged out of the CCP, but it doesn't seem like it necessarily the case as I don't think he said anything negative against Xi publicly, I might be wrong, but that led me to wonder if Xi has any big critic within the CCP as it seems like the CCP has become a big echo chamber and that everyone who might have been a threat to him was purged out of the government a long time ago.

Comment: This question might not understand how China works. Going around and saying that you are a critic of Xi Jinping will quickly strip you of all your powers. What may work though might be a hidden critic. Somebody who officially nods and unofficially criticizes him. But these people might be hard to find out. Not even sure that it would be a good idea to publicly make them known.

Comment: It's also not clear what "big critic within the CCP" means - the CCP has 98 million members so are you including rank-and-file members (academics, journalists, businesspeople, pop singers, etc, who may have wealth, influence, or a public audience), or specifically those who hold formal positions of power in the CCP?